# ora-49204: recursive dde invocation at phase i - after switchover to standby

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, dataguard

I am currently testing a data guard environment. After a switchover, which is performed successfully, I can see the following error in the alert.log of the new stand:

ora-49204: recursive dde invocation at phase i
This error is followed by ora-01110.
This happens for all data files.

The standby is running in open mode read only.
I checked the database for logical and physical block corruption via rman.
Everything looks good.

How do I have to interpret this error?
I am using the base version of Oracle 12cR2.

I would appreciate, if anyone could give me some hint.

Best regards

IronMike

Answer (score 1):

Per Oracle Support, this is probably a bug
https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/2322290_1.html

Function kcidr_file_header_check_common is File Header check which cause of this issue. If you see this in the Stack Trace and Standby opens Read only successfully then you are most likely encountering this bug.